# how to crop the detected object in image with Object's bounding box using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop, matlab-cvst

Hi. I am new to image processing. I want to extract detected region of image as new image. I detect the eye region of face using `caseCadeObjectDetector` method. Now I would like to know, how to extract the detected region of image. Here is what I did.

```
i=imread('test.jpg');
Eyedetect =  vision.CascadeObjectDetector('RightEye','MergeThreshold',24);
bbox=step(Eyedetect,i);
```

I plot that bounding box using `insertObjectAnnotation` method. It plots the line over the eye. But I want to crop that eye as new image. bbox is 1x4 matrix contains `x , y, height, width`.
Can anybody help me? I am using MATLAB r2013a.

Answer (score 4):

To extract the sub-image with `bbox` in format `[x, y, height, width]`, you can use:

```
subImage = i(bbox(1):bbox(1)+bbox(3), bbox(2):bbox(2)+bbox(4), :);
```

---

**P.S.** If `bbox` is in format `[x, y, width, height]`, you can simply call [`imcrop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html):

```
subImage = imcrop(i, bbox);
```